# Laravel looping data in controller from separate DB?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, eloquent

Hello i stuck with my problem, so i want to ask you for help.

That's my problem. I need to get something like this (This code doesn't work):

```
    public function getSingle($slug)
    {
$galeries = Galeries::where('kat_id', Blogs::get('gal_id'))->get();
}
```

I have no idea how to get this to @foreach in my page with this code:

```
@foreach($galeries as $galery)
    <!-- project item -->
    <li class="project-item mix branding">
        <a href="../public/assets/img/galery/{{ $galery->img }}" class="fancybox" data-rel="portfolio">
            <div class="project-img">
                <img class="project-img" src="../public/assets/img/galery/{{ $galery->img }}" alt="project"/>
            </div>

        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- / project item -->
@endforeach
```

Please Help :) Greetings.

Edit: I think I did not give all the information. I want do add show gallery in a single post sellect by category (gal_id). `Galery have imgs data [id and kat_id], Category [id]  so Category [id]  = Galery[kat_id] and single post have Blogs[gal_id] = Category [id]` So if Blogs[id] = '1' show only img from  Galerys[kat_id] = '1'

Ok solved: I need add some hanges to code from @Peter Pere: `$galeries = DB::table('blogs')->where('slug', $slug)->join('galeries', 'galeries.kat_id', '=', 'blogs.gal_id')->get();`

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: `code $galeries = Galeries::where('kat_id', Blogs::get('gal_id'))->get();`   This code doesn't work

Comment: What is the relation between `Galeries` and `Blogs`? Could you post the models as well?

Comment: I think I did not give all the information. I want do add show gallery in a single post sellect by category (gal_id). `Galery have imgs data [id and kat_id], Category [id]  so Category [id]  = Galery[kat_id] and single post have Blogs[gal_id] = Category [id] ` So if Blogs[id] = '1' show only img from  Galerys[kat_id] = '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line above your controller class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

and then this is the right code to write:

```
$galeries = DB::table('galeries')
    ->join('blogs', 'galeries.kat_id', '=', 'blogs.gal_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Actually yes it's a right code but all the posts have gal_id from the first post, even if in DB have another. I think I did not give all the information. I want do add show gallery in a single post sellect by category (gal_id). `Galery have imgs data [id and kat_id], Category [id]  so Category [id]  = Galery[kat_id] and single post have Blogs[gal_id] = Category [id] ` So if Blogs[id] = '1' show only img from Galerys[kat_id] = '1'.

Comment: and i need to hange position blogs with galeries `$galeries = DB::table('blogs')->join('galeries', 'galeries.kat_id', '=', 'blogs.gal_id')->get();`

Comment: Ok solved: I need add some hanges : `$galeries = DB::table('blogs')->where('slug', $slug)->join('galeries', 'galeries.kat_id', '=', 'blogs.gal_id')->get();`  Thanks

Comment: ok, yea... just mark the answer as CORRECT, so it appears in the forum as solved